# Oracle SQL Results duplicating with join

Tags: oracle

I am trying to use the following code :

```
SELECT a.part_no,
       sum(a.BUY_QTY_DUE) AS Tot_Ord,
       sum(b.REVISED_QTY_DUE) AS S_O_Tot
FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER_JOIN a
LEFT OUTER JOIN SHOP_ORD b ON a.part_no= b.part_no
AND b.contract = '20'
AND b.state = 'Planned'
WHERE a.PART_NO = '10002261'
  AND a.OBJSTATE = 'Released'
  AND a.CONTRACT = '10'
GROUP BY a.part_no
```

However I am seeing duplicated results, I know this is to do with the join but not sure how to fix :(
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX2GK.png)

The results I expect to see are,

`Tot_Ord = 277`
(6 instances of 23, 3 instances of 46, 1 instance of 1) 10 lines in total

`S_O_Tot = 46`
(2 instances of 23) 2 lines in Total

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks,

Jamie

Comment: Provide sample data set as it would be beneficial for others to come up answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.part_no,
sum(a.BUY_QTY_DUE) AS Tot_Ord,
sum(nvl(b.REVISED_QTY_DUE,0)) AS S_O_Tot
FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER_JOIN a
LEFT OUTER JOIN SHOP_ORD b ON (a.part_no= b.part_no
AND b.contract = '20'
AND b.state = 'Planned')
WHERE a.PART_NO = '10002261'
AND a.OBJSTATE = 'Released'
AND a.CONTRACT = '10'
```

I have deleted grouping because you are filtering on this filed anyway